# Access VBA: Run-time error '13' Type mismatch

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

```
Set wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(fileName)
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Sheet1")
cn.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & fileName & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;"";"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tracking", dbOpenTable)
ws.Cells.ClearFormats
```

The bug trigger according to access is

```
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tracking", dbOpenTable)
```

as "Type mismatch". I have already build a table name as "Tracking" in my access application, so I was confused why it is not processed.

PS. I am trying to add new records from Excel to Access table through recordset.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: it will be `cn.openrecordset` maybe?

Comment: How do you set `db`? Where are you calling the code from? Can you replace `dbOpenTable` with `1` and see whether it would work? - like this - `Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tracking", 1)`

Comment: rs.open works only for DAO.recordset. But I used ADODB.recordset... So I don't think this would work...

Comment: `Set db = CurrentDb
    Set xl = New Excel.Application
    Set cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset`

Comment: @SylviaLiu - I thought that you were calling it from Excel, thus the enumeration of Access is not recognized. In Access, it should be working without a problem, the Access library is present there by default.

Comment: You're mixing ADODB and DAO code. You can't do that. `db.OpenRecordset` returns a DAO.Recordset. I can't provide further help unless you share the full code, including all variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem does not have anything to do with Excel. In order to help somehow, there should be a way to make a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which would actually be enough for everyone to copy, paste it and replicate the error.

Something like this in Access is quite enough:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim rs As Recordset
    Dim db As Database: Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("Tracking", dbOpenTable)

End Sub
```

If you still have problems with even this code, then it is a good start.

Comment: I tried this with a separate module without any error pops up. But I was still have this error back in the original code part. So it could be triggered due to other lines?

Comment: @SylviaLiu - I don't know. But it is a start. What I would do now is either to **A)** Slowly integrate additional lines in the code that works and see which one is the one that breaks it or **B)** See where exactly the error is on the old code - with step-by-step debugging and F9.